# How to align section on center in horizontal navigation?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website is for horizontal navigation with section 960px who are 
call with anchors (such as a slide show) and I wanted to align
my sections with center, depending on the size of the window.

This the code :

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section" id="section1">test</div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">test2</div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">test3</div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">test4</div>
  </div>

#wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 5000px;
}

.section{
  width: 960px;
  height: 576px;
  float: left;
}
```

Is align center when I load page but not with navigation anchor.

Help me please

Thanks.

Comment: Why is your wrapper 5000px wide?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not do something similar?...

```
.wrapper {width:960px;}
ul#nav {width:auto; margin:0 auto;}

<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
        Nav links
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but the wrapper had 5000px in width not 960px.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 display : table-cell;
 vertical-align : middle;
```

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display)**

Comment: No, i wanna center in horizontal, like this http://dsebastien.delrue.free.fr/random/zabeth/